# Why is scoring a separate problem even after docking is done?

Tags: machine-learning, computational-chemistry, computational-biology

With regards to protein-ligand interactions, we talk about two concepts, *docking* and *scoring*. I understand that *docking* means to find the best orientation of a ligand at the active site of a protein, and *scoring* is to compare several docked ligands to see which ligand best binds to the protein.

To quote [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ci500319f),

> "While there is now a general consensus that most of the popular
>   docking algorithms perform fairly well in generating sound poses,
>   scoring functions most often fail to adequately evaluate the binding
>   affinity."

What does it mean to be *docked*, if not being the pose with the best binding affinity? If not, how is docking done without calculation of binding affinity?

Comment: This may not be the right place to ask this question (it's more a biochemistry question), but my take is that docking is a geometric problem: Which ligand fits geometrically onto which protein. On the other hand, scoring is about how closely they bind. Just because you can fit a round peg into a square hole doesn't mean you've already figured out how tightly it sits there.

Comment: This question would be of interest on the new Materials Modeling SE: https://materials.stackexchange.com/